# Icon for viewing document that's easy to understand

Tags: icons, ux-designer, standards

The page contains a table and each row's last cell contains a **hyperlink** which redirects the user to a document.

> What icon would be best suited in replacing this link to a document?

I was thinking either;

- a small **eye** icon (as to view)
- a small **doc** icon

Comment: Maybe you can just change a color of document name, like a visited link..

Comment: You should give a little more context for better judgement. But I would choose doc over eye since it's easier to guess

Comment: @Big_Chair updated.

Comment: I was more looking for a standard than a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, **a small doc icon** will serve its best purpose in your case.

Or else you can try a fusion of both, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I don't suppose there's an industry standard for such an icon?

Comment: Thanks! I can't comment on, whether it is a standard or not? But I can assure you, it should be well acceptable under the industry defined design terms conferring the end users perceptibility.

Answer (score 0):

Having two different icons may mislead the user to thing of two different files/records rather two different states.

So I would suggest to have icons as close as possible. 
You can have:

- document icon with small eye(or a tick) in the bottom right corner for "Viewed Document"
- document icon with small plus sign in the bottom right corner for "New Document"

Comment: please see edit